# convert 16-Bit to 8-Bit images

Tags: matlab, image-preprocessing

I am using matlab, and I need to convert 16-bit images to 8-bit images (tif extention) , 
and I used

```
image = im2uint8(16bit_img);
image = uint8(16bit_img/256);
```

and both of these methods are giving me matrix with same intensity numbers as shown in the pictures (the first one is the original 16-bit image, the second one is after conversion to 8-bit)

[image: 16 bit image]

[image: 8-bit image after conversion]

However, converting the image to 8-bit using other software such as ImageJ, it gives different (reasonable) values as shown below

[image: imageJ conversion]

Can anyone explain the reason why it has different output?